# Is it possible to only use some functions of an assembly file?

Tags: assembly, keil, 8051

I'm using uVision (Keil) together with an 8051 uController

Lets say I have a main.asm file like this (it does not do anything, just for used for example)

```
; MAIN FILE

extrn      code (func1)
extrn      code (func2)

org 0x0000
    sjmp    main

main:
    mov     a, r0
    lcall   func1
    mov     a, r1
    lcall   func2

    sjmp    $

end
```

Also lets say I'm using a functions.asm file with some good to have functions. (same with this file.. does not do anything, just for example)

```
; FUNCTIONS FILE

public     func1, func2, func3

my_seg     segment code
           rseg    my_seg

func1:
           ; do something
           ret

func2:
           ; do something else
           ret

func3:
           ; do something amazing
           ret

end
```

When I compile this code 'func3' is included in the hex file even though I never call it. I can accept that..

**Questions:**
How should I do if I want to create some sort of generic library that I can include in my projects without producing a giant hex file?

Comment: Read the documentation for the linker you're using. It may provide some sort of option for removing unused sections/segments (note that this might require you to place each function in its own section/segment).

Comment: Put each function into its own object, link them into a static library, and then the linker usually does the right thing.

Comment: @Jester Okay,I've never done that. How do I do that? Create a file for each function and then what?

Comment: Assemble each to object and then use your toolchain's library tool. Not familiar with keil, unfortunately.

Comment: Got it to work... partially at least :) Couldn't complete the action since I'm using an evaluation version of Keil..
Thanks anyway!

Comment: If you want a full Keil Toolchain you may go to Silab Website ( for example as if you were using a 8051F040 uC. Register and get a SN number from Silab. Then use this SN on Keil Website to get the full toolchain ( for example for the family of the uC I mentioned above )